# In xquery when fn:upper-case() with apostrophe ", single quote receiving error

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql, xquery-3.0

In Xquery for the using the function fn:upper-case when we use apostrophe (') and double quotes (") getting below parser error. please let me know if any inputs on this error.

earch failed to execute, please check XQuery for possible issues: query:1:104:XQUERY_PARSE_ERROR: query:1:104:XQUERY_PARSE_ERROR: illegal entity reference: unexpected 'Q', expected &, >, <, ', or a character reference (XPST0003) query:1:114:XQUERY_PARSE_ERROR: illegal entity reference: unexpected 'Q', expected &, >, <, ', or a character reference (XPST0003) , Original message: illegal entity reference: unexpected 'Q', expected &, >, <, ', or a character reference (XPST0003) for $elem in /CSCHULMAN_DEV/CSCHULMAN_IA_INVOICE/ROW where contains(fn:upper-case($elem/ONSDES) ,'ERR/"ABD/"') return $elem -------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your XQuery code has a string literal with the sequence `&Q` which breaks the syntax rules and would need to be `&amp;Q`.

Comment: Thanks actually below statement. resolved. One problem for each special character the replacement character is different let $ONSDES := fn:replace(fn:upper-case($ONSDES),'&amp;QUOT;','&amp;quot;')
let $ONSDES := fn:replace($ONSDES,'&amp;APOS;','&amp;apos;')